# Server-Ip address is not getting displayed in snmp-trap messages

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

my problem is about Ip Address which I am receiving on the windows system snmp-trap messages,is some thing like that `UDP: [192.168.1.150]:1029->[0.0.0.0]:0`

while same trap message on linux system has been displayed as

```
UDP: [192.168.1.150]:1030->[192.168.1.23]
```

Now,if you observed carefully these two ,its clearly shown that server ip is not coming in windows traps-Ip(`[0.0.0.0]:0`).what would be the possible reason?please anyone can help me about understanding this & can provide the solution for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try running tcpdump on both machines to record your snmp messages.
What version on snmp are you running? Is the 0.0.0.0 supposed to be the linux box?
Then this would be a linux vs windows issue....

Comment: How is this not useful..? Irrelevent? @Chris S